# Shell Scripting, Killing Process after a Time execution period

Tags: linux, shell, process, linux-kernel, makefile

I am writing a makefile to execute a program in C, time the execution for a second, and terminate the process using the PID. I have copy pasted my Makefile below:

Makefile:

build:

```
gcc -o parse.out bst.c parse.c

gcc -o tree.out bst.c tree-search.c
```

1:

```
./parse.out < gettysburg.txt > myOutput/test1.result

diff actual/test1.result myOutput/test1.result
```

2:

```
./parse.out < king-speech.txt > myOutput/test2.result

diff actual/test2.result myOutput/test2.result
```

3:

```
./tree.out < testFile1 > myOutput/test3.result &

sleep 1

kill -9  $(ps aux | grep './tree.out' | head -n1 | awk '{print $2}')

diff actual/test3.result myOutput/test3.result
```

4:

```
./tree.out < testFile2 > myOutput/test4.result &

sleep 0.5

kill -9 $(ps aux | grep './tree.out' | head -n1 | awk '{print $2}')

diff actual/test4.result myOutput/test4.result
```

clean:

```
rm -f *.o
```

Below I have attached a link to the image of my results:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/07v7O.jpg

For some reason, the process isn't being killed upon execution of the Makefile, but then if I run the kill command again manually, the process gets killed. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it would be a lot easier to help you if you actually provided the makefile: how can we tell what's wrong with it if you don't show it to us?

However, my suspicion is that you forgot to escape the dollar signs; dollar signs are special to make so you have to double them whenever you use them in a make recipe:

```
kill -9 $$(ps aux | grep './tree.out' | head -n1 | awk '{print $$2}')
```